# When is it necessary to use proof by induction?

Tags: linear-algebra, polynomials, solution-verification

> Suppose $T \in \mathcal{L} (V)$ and $U$ is a subspace of $V$ invariant
> under $T$. Prove that $U$ is invariant under $p(T)$ for every
> polynomial $p \in \mathcal{P} (\mathbb{F})$.

$\underline{\textrm{My attempt at the solution:}}$

Suppose $p (z) \in \mathcal{P}(\mathbb{F})$. Write $p (z) = \sum_{j=0}^{m} a_{j} z^{j}$ where $z \in \mathbb{F}$.
By definition, $p (T) = \sum_{j=0}^{m} a_{j} T^{j}$.
Then, for any $u \in U$, we have
\begin{align*}
p (T) (u) = \left( \sum_{j=0}^{m} a_{j} T^{j} \right) (u) = \sum_{j=0}^{m} a_{j} (T^{j} u)
\end{align*}

$\underline{Claim}:$ $T^{n} u \in U$ for any $n \in \mathbb{N}^{+}$.

Prove by induction:

1. Base case: $T^{0} u = I u = u \in U$.
2. Induction hypothesis: $T^{n} u \in U$.
3. Induction proof: Note $T^{n+1} u = T (T^{n} u)$. Because $U$ is invariant under $T$, we have $T(T^{n} u) \in U$.
   Therefore, $T^{n+1} u \in U$ for $n \in \mathbb{N}$.
   Hence the result.

By the inductive result, we have $T^{j} u \in U$ for all $j$. Since $U$ is a subspace of $V$, it is closed under addition and scalar multiplication. Therefore, $\sum_{j=0}^{m} a_{j} (T^{j} u) \in U$. By definition, $U$ is invariant under $p (T)$ for any $p \in \mathcal{P} (\mathbb{F})$.

$\underline{\textrm{Question:}}$

Would it be necessary to also prove by induction that this result holds for $p \in \mathcal{P} (\mathbb{F})$ of any degree? I thought it wouldn't be necessary since the choice of $m$ was arbitrary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you use a summation formula (these are *defined* by recursion, but you can assume those are well-defined, because you have to start somewhere, right?) and so the argument is valid and general as it stands.

There is a background (previously done?) argument hidden in that summation, namely that a subspace is closed under all *finite* sums, so that indeed from $\alpha_i \in U$ for $i=1,\ldots,m$ we can conclude $\sum_{i=1}^m \alpha_i \in U$. This is a completely standard induction argument based on the recursive definition of the summation $\sum_{i=1}^m \alpha_i$. I would assume that as a fact and not reprove it every time. The fact that $T^m(u) \in U$ for all natural $m$ and $u \in U$ is a special case of the full polynomial result and so IMO it merits a place as a minor lemma here.